# jquery and RadioButton changed event

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a group of radio buttons all with the same name.
I use a selector to attach the `.changed` event to the radio button grouup by the name. 
The event fires but the `.val()` of the radio button group is the value of the group before the change not after the change.
How do I get the value after the change, there has to be something I'm doing wrong.

```
$('[name="Messages"]').click(function () { 
    someFunction('Messages', $('[name="Messages"]').val()) 
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want the value for the particular radio button that was clicked on. You can use `$(this).val()` to get it. Otherwise you need to clarify, there's no such thing as a "group value". Each individual radio button should have it's own value.

```
$('[name="Messages"]').click(function () { 
    someFunction('Messages', $(this).val());  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not filtering out unselected radio buttons, therefore your click will always bring back the value of the first radio button in the DOM. Try filtering out on `:checked`:

```
$('[name="Messages"]').click(function () { 
    someFunction('Messages',$('[name="Messages"]:checked').val());
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T7Q8T/

Comment: The one that's clicked on will be the one that's checked! No need to requery the DOM.

Comment: Hmmm it looks like I've overcomplicated this one! I tried yours in a Fiddle and it worked, I suspected that it wouldn't but I take my hat off to you, +1 for yours :)